# Java String encoding (UTF-8)

Tags: java, string, encoding

I have come across this line of legacy code, which I am trying to figure out:

```
String newString = new String(oldString.getBytes("UTF-8"), "UTF-8"));
```

As far as I can understand, it is encoding & decoding using the same charSet.

How is this different from the following?

```
String newString = oldString;
```

**Is there any scenario in which the two lines will have different outputs?**

p.s.: Just to clarify, yes I am aware of the [excellent article on encoding by Joel Spolsky](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) !

Comment: Well of course, *one* difference is that with `String newString = oldString;`, you still only have one copy of the string (you're just pointing to it from two variables). The decode/encode makes a *copy* of the string. Not that it matters much, since `String`s are immutable. This probably isn't why that old code is that way, though; `String` has a much more direct way to clone itself (`String(String)`). I can't think of a *good* reason why you'd do the encoding/decoding, other than testing the `String` class's encoding/decoding methods.

Comment: Does the context give any hint why string conversion may have or had been necessary?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: +1 , ofcourse! I did not mean the difference in the actual object referred. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: There is one more major difference: one of them does not compile ;-)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This could be complicated way of doing

```
String newString = new String(oldString);
```

This shortens the String is the underlying char[] used is much longer.

However more specifically it will be checking that every character can be UTF-8 encoded.

There are some "characters" you can have in a String which cannot be encoded and these would be turned into `?`

Any character between \uD800 and \uDFFF cannot be encoded and will be turned into '?'

```
String oldString = "\uD800";
String newString = new String(oldString.getBytes("UTF-8"), "UTF-8");
System.out.println(newString.equals(oldString));
```

prints

```
false
```

Comment: The only reason `oldString` fails to encode properly is because it is not a valid UTF-16 (native representation of strings in Java) string to begin with. UTF-8 is fully capable of encoding any and all Unicode code points itself. In this case, there would be a difference only when `oldString` contains an invalid sequence of UTF-16 bytes.

Answer (score 4):

> How is this different from the following?

This line of code here:

```
String newString = new String(oldString.getBytes("UTF-8"), "UTF-8"));
```

constructs a new String object (i.e. a copy of `oldString`), while this line of code:

```
String newString = oldString;
```

declares a new variable of type `java.lang.String` and initializes it to refer to the same String object as the variable `oldString`.

> Is there any scenario in which the two lines will have different outputs?

Absolutely:

```
String newString = oldString;
boolean isSameInstance = newString == oldString; // isSameInstance == true
```

vs.

```
String newString = new String(oldString.getBytes("UTF-8"), "UTF-8"));
 // isSameInstance == false (in most cases)    
boolean isSameInstance = newString == oldString;
```

a_horse_with_no_name (see comment) is right of course. The equivalent of

```
String newString = new String(oldString.getBytes("UTF-8"), "UTF-8"));
```

is

```
String newString = new String(oldString);
```

minus the subtle difference wrt the encoding that Peter Lawrey explains in his answer.

Comment: `String newString = new String(oldString)` would be equivalent to the "original" line I guess