# Android byte to string charset

Tags: java, android, character-encoding

I have a problem with the charset convertion:

I have got messages from udp server and I get the data like this:

```
byte[] adress= new byte [42];
```

After I try to displayed to textview :

```
String str_adress= new String(adress,"UTF-8");
```

Instead of "ő" I got just "?"

How can I solve that?

Comment: Well.. it seems your byte array source wasn't UTF-8 encoded. I think you should try to figure out the correct encoding.

Comment: Ive tried this too

`String str_adress= new String(adress,"ISO-8859-1");`

Comment: Give this a try `String newString = new String(oldString.getBytes("UTF-8"), "UTF-8");`
Maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8854106/java-string-encoding-utf-8 this will help

Comment: I have tried your code but doesnt work :S

Answer (score 0):

The UTF-8 bytes for `ő` are `c5 91`.

As

```
Log.v(TAG, new String(new byte[] { (byte) 0xc5, (byte) 0x91 }, "UTF-8"));
```

outputs

```
ő
```

I think you looked in the wrong place for the problem. It's coming from somewhere else, like reading the udp message maybe.

Comment: I just got 63 not  c5 91. I got a byte stream from the server so I just read the buffer.

Comment: @meklod400: 63?? That's the ASCII code (and Unicode codepoint) for `?`! So the **server** is already sending a `?` and *nothing* you do on the client will turn that into something else. Fix the server!