# How compare text UTF-8 in android?

Tags: android, utf-8, string-comparison

My code not working when compare text UTF-8:

```
 String a="Mão";


    String getTimeGioAm(String a)
    {
        String time="";
        if (a.equals("Mão")) {
            time = "6-8";
        }
       return time ;
    }
```

result: `time=""`
How compare text UTF-8 in android?

Comment: How exactly is it not working? Because I don't see anything wrong with the if.

Comment: You have to show more code, pal. Or your logcat.

Comment: It not go into command if

Comment: And where are you calling getTimeGioAm(String a)?

Comment: There's no UTF-8 in the code you posted.
Your `a` variable is not the same as the argument `a` in `getTimeGioAm(String a)`. Is this your problem?

Comment: value of a get from file txt

Comment: Please edit the question to contain something to actually reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
String a="Mão";
String aux_a = new String(a.getBytes("UTF-8"), "UTF-8");
String time="";
if (someString.equals(aux_a)) {
    time = "6-8";
}
```

An interesting discussion about UTF-8 strings [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8854243/1668144)