# Android insert emoji programmatically

Tags: android, utf-8, emoji

I'm trying to implement emojis in a way that I automatically replace things like ":)" with their emoji equivalent. And I'm not really sure how to do that, I found a table of emoji UTF codes, but I'm not sure on how I'm supposed to programmatically put them into a EditText :/

```
 inputField=(EditText)temp.findViewById(R.id.inputField);
    inputField.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        boolean justChanged=false;
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            if(justChanged) {
                justChanged=false;
                return;
            }
            Log.d(s.toString(), s.toString());
            if(s.toString().contains(":)")) {
                justChanged=true;
               inputField.setText(s.toString().replace(":)", "UTF CODE HERE?"));
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: If your current approach listed here doesn't work explain what it does wrong.

Comment: It's not that it "doesn't work", I just can't figure out on how to put emoji codes into a String variable :/ I need an example, because just pasting it in there gives that exact code as plain text

Comment: Have you tried this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8854437/1510063 ?

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way is to achieve this is to encode your source code as UTF-8, and paste your desired emoji into the code. You will then need to pass `-encoding UTF-8` to `javac`. The emoji will then be converted to its Unicode point on compilation.

E.g.

```
inputField.setText(s.toString().replace(":)", ""));
```

Alternatively, you can use UTF-16 Unicode point literals within Java strings, using the `\uXXXX` notation. From a suitable Unicode reference site, such as, http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/block/emoticons/list.htm, you can get the UTF-16 type encoding or the complete Java escape sequence.

E.g.

```
inputField.setText(s.toString().replace(":)", "\uD83D\uDE00"));
```

Comment: the link you provided is not the complete list of emojis..,isn't it?

Comment: I tried the code above, does not work. Just sends out :   "\uD83D\uDE00" instead of ":)" This absolutely does not answer the question at all. It does no good if the recipient gets a string of this: "\uD83D\uDE00". There is a serious lack of clarity and openness surrounding emojis. This shouldn't be difficult, we are not trying to change the look of the emoji so why can't this be done?

Comment: What do you mean "it just sends out"? The answer shows two ways of putting emojis in the source code. Which one are you using?