# Android compare UTF-8 string with UTF-8 input string of edittext

Tags: android, utf-8

In my android application, i want to compare an utf-8 string, for example **"bãi"** with string which user type on edittext.
However, if I type **"bãi"** to edittext and get input string by using method edittext.getText().toString(), it will return string like [image: input string]

and it will not equal **"bãi"**

I also try

```
String input = new String(input.getBytes("UTF-8"), "UTF-8");
```

but it not work. input.equals("bãi") will return false.

Is anyone know how solve this problem.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: This question isn't a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8854106/java-string-encoding-utf-8. It's centers around the representation of "ã", which is probably given as a single Unicode codepoint (U+00E3) in the first case and as two separate ones (U+0061 and U+0303) in the second case.

Comment: Normalize your strings first before comparing them. This should get rid of differences related to combining characters. See [Normalizer](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/Normalizer.html).

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya: Please reopen the question. It's not a duplicate as you'll see when you read it carefully.

Comment: I've added a proper answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Unicode, certain characters can be represented in more than one way. For example, in the word *bãi* the middle character can be represented in two ways:

1. a single codepoint U+00E3 (LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH TILDE)
2. two codepoints U+0061 (LATIN SMALL LETTER A) and U+0303 (COMBINING TILDE)

For display, both should look the same.

For string comparison, this poses a problem. The solution is to normalize the strings first according to [Unicode Standard Annex #15 — Unicode Normalization Forms](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr15/tr15-23.html).

Normalization is supported in Java (incl. Android) by the [Normalizer class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/Normalizer.html) (for Android see [Normalizer](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/Normalizer.html)).

The code below shows the result:

```
String s1 = "b\u00e3i";
String s2 = "ba\u0303i";
System.out.println(String.format("Before normalization: %s == %s => %b", s1, s2, s1.equals(s2)));

String n1 = Normalizer.normalize(s1, Form.NFD);
String n2 = Normalizer.normalize(s2, Form.NFD);
System.out.println(String.format("After normalization:  %s == %s => %b", n1, n2, n1.equals(n2)));
```

It outputs:

```
Before normalization: bãi == bãi => false
After normalization:  bãi == bãi => true
```

BTW: The form `Form.NFD` decomposes the strings, i.e. it creates the longer representation with two codepoints. `Form.NFC` would create the shorter form.

Comment: thank Codo for detail answer. It has solved my problem.